# no file in transfer queue through WatchConnectivity and WCSession

Tags: watchkit, watchconnectivity

I'm trying to send a data file from Apple Watch to paired iPhone through WatchConnectivity. My code is as following:

```
    let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self.storedData, options : .prettyPrinted)

    let str = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(str)

    var fileName = ""
    let tempDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    fileName = tempDirectory + "test.json"

    if self.fileManager.createFile(atPath: fileName, contents: data
        , attributes: nil) {
        print("New file creation went through!")
    }

    if self.fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileName) {
        print("File created @ \(fileName)")
    } else {
        print("Something wrong when creating file @ \(fileName)")
    }

    var fileTransferString = "file://"
    fileTransferString += fileName

    let url = URL(string: fileTransferString)
    self.session.transferFile(url!, metadata: nil)
     print("\(self.session.outstandingFileTransfers.count) files in the transfer queue!")
```

Although I got the message that "File created @...", the following message by the last line "print" is always "0 files in the transfer queue!" I didn't find any object failed to initiate or nil throughout the process. It just seems that the file was created but the "session.transferFile" function just didn't go through.

Can anybody help me on some hints regarding where the problem is and how to solve it?

Thank you all!

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last two lines to:

```
self.session.transferFile(url!, metadata: nil)
DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosUserInitiated).async {
     print("\(self.session.outstandingFileTransfers.count) files in the transfer queue!")
}
```

Any difference?